# Blocking/disabling picture box when that number is picked. Deal or No Deal Game C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a deal or no deal game. I have 22 picture boxes. 11 on one side and the other 11 on the other. With the boxes that the user can pick in the middle. I wan't to remove or disable the relevant picture box when the box that contains that amount is picked. The amount of money the box contains is created randomly. So say for instance box 15 contains 100000. I want to remove the picture box which holds the image of the £100,000. Is there any way in which I could do this?

Here is my global arrays etc:

```
double[] box = new double[22];
    double[] values = new double[22] {0.01, 0.10, 0.50, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 3000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 35000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 250000};
    //PictureBox[] picturbox = new PictureBox[22];
    Random myrand = new Random();
    bool start = true;
    //bool pick = true;
    int count = 0;
```

Here is my code for creating the random values:

```
 private void frm_dealornodeal_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       txt_bankersOffer.Hide();         // hiding text until box is picked
       txt_offer.Hide();                 // hiding text until box is picked
       bool Found = false;              
       int Rand_Loc = myrand.Next(22);  //random number generator for the boxes

       box[0] = values[Rand_Loc];
       values[Rand_Loc] = 0;

       for (int x = 1; x < 22; x++ )
       {
           Found = true;
           while (Found)
           {
               Found = false;
               Rand_Loc = myrand.Next(22);
               if (values[Rand_Loc] != 0)
               {
                   box[x] = values[Rand_Loc];
                   values[Rand_Loc] = 0;
               }
               else
               {
                   Found = true;
               }
           }

       }



   }
```

& finally here is the code that I have for a button click event when they are picking their boxes. The code for all the other boxes is the same.

```
private void btn_box_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (start == true)
       {
           start = false;               
           pic_pick.Hide();
           btn_box_2.Location = new Point(584, 543);

       }
       else
       {
           txt_boxContentsText.Show();
           txt_boxcontentsnuber.Show();
           txt_bankersOffer.Hide();
           txt_offer.Hide();
           txt_boxcontentsnuber.Text = Convert.ToString(box[2 - 1]);
           btn_box_2.Enabled = false;
           btn_box_2.BackColor = Color.Gray;
           count++;
       }

       if (count == 5 || count == 8 || count == 11 || count == 14 || count == 17 || count == 20)
       {
           txt_boxContentsText.Show();
           txt_boxcontentsnuber.Show();
           txt_bankersOffer.Show();
           txt_offer.Show();
           txt_offer.Text = Convert.ToString(1000);
       }

   }
```

While I'm here could anyone come up with a good formula that I could use to give them the bankers offers?

Cheers.

Picture of form:
(You cant see the last picture box for the left hand side £750 or the right hand side £250,000 but they are there.)

[image: You cant see the last picture box for the left hand side £750 or the right hand side £250,000 but they are there.]

Comment: It seems like you already have it: `btn_box_2.Enabled=false` should cause the click event to not be accepted (if it does, just check in the handler if it has been clicked already!) What is your question?

Comment: I think ive confused you a little by saying pictureboxes and boxes. I know the american show uses suitcases. So ill explain it like that. I have 11 picture boxes on the left hand side & 11 on the other which display pics with values from 0.01p to £250,000. In the middle between these are 22 buttons that represent the "suitcases". The values inside these "suitcases" are randomly generated out of a list of 22 numbers. When one of these suitcases is picked the player will see the value in a textbox and at  the same time I want the picture that reprsents that value to disappear.pic of from above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of `Control.Tag` property. Each button's tag can contain the name of the corresponding `PictureBox`. You can then disable the picture box in the click event. You also do not need 22 separate click events if they all do the same thing, since `object sender` parameter tells you which button was clicked, and the `Tag` property will tell you which `PictureBox` to disable.

To address the random assignment of button values, here's a solution:

1. Assign a value to each `PictureBox.Tag` property representing the value (since the PictureBoxes do not change, only the buttons do, in my understanding). So, if the value is 0.01 set that as Tag value; if it's 0.50, set 0.5 as the Tag value; 1.0 should be set to 1, and so on.
2. Differentiate "Suitcase" buttons by name, such as "Suitcase1", "Suitcase2", etc.
3. Use the following technique to randomly assign these values to your buttons (you can call this function at Form_Load event):

   ```
   private void assignButtonValues()
   { 
       Random random = new Random();
       List<double> values = new List<Double>( new[] {0.01, 0.10, 0.50, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 3000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 35000, 50000, 75000, 100000, 250000} );

       foreach (Button button in Controls.OfType<Button>())
       {
           //Is this a suitcase or just some button in the game?
           if (button.Name.Contains("Suitcase"))
           { 
               //select random value and remove it from the list of values to ensure it's assigned to only one button
               double buttonValue = values[random.Next(0, values.Count)];
               values.Remove(buttonValue);

               //TODO: Your code to save the value in an array, etc, for later processing, etc.

               //Assign corresponding picture to this button's tag
               button.Tag = Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
                                    .Where<PictureBox>(p => p.Tag.ToString() == buttonValue.ToString())
                                    .First<PictureBox>().Name;
           }
       }     
   }
   ```
4. Use the `processButtons` function as the event handler for all buttons:

   ```
   private void processButtons(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //Get the clicked button
       Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
       string correspondingPictureBoxName = clickedButton.Tag.ToString();

       //Get the corresponding PictureBox
       PictureBox correspondingPictureBox = (PictureBox)Controls.Find(correspondingPictureBoxName, true).First<Control>();

       //Hide the PictureBox
       correspondingPictureBox.Visible = false;
   }
   ```

Comment: Can I still do this with the tag if the numbers are random? For example the button number 1 may have 10p in it for one game, but in the next one it might have £100,000. Would your advice still work? Cheers for the other tip!

Comment: I changed my original answer to address the random assignment of button values. See if that helps you. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers for your help, ill try implement it now!

Comment: @COYG, if my solution worked for you, would you please kindly accept it as an answer? If it didn't, please specify what went wrong (I tested it prior to posting), and I'll help you further. Thank you!